# Scatter Plot Not Updating With Widget Selection in Python Panel Holoviz

Tags: python, pandas, hvplot, holoviz, holoviz-panel

I want a Python Panel app with dynamic plots, and different plots depending on which menu/button is selected from a sidepanel, so I started from this great starting point: https://discourse.holoviz.org/t/multi-page-app-documentation/3108/2

Each page had a sine & cosine plot which updated based on widget values, using `@pn.depends`.

Then I updated the code so that the sine plot would be a scatter plot, and the widget would be a selection drop-down menu instead of a slider. But now that scatter plot is not updating when I update the selection drop-down widget. What am I doing wrong? Clearly I’m misunderstanding something about what `@pn.depends()` is doing or not doing. Any help would be super appreciated!

Full code (`app.py`) below:

```
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import holoviews as hv
import hvplot.pandas
import numpy as np
import time
from datetime import datetime

pn.extension()

template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(title='My Dashboard')

# load detailed data
durations = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
activity_codes = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3']
activity_categories = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': durations,
                   'ActivityCode': activity_codes,
                   'ActivityCategory': activity_categories})


# Page 1 Widget Controls
ac_categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ac_cat_radio_button = pn.widgets.Select(name='Activity Category', options=ac_categories)


# Page 1 Plotting Code
@pn.depends(ac_cat=ac_cat_radio_button)
def scatter_detail_by_ac(df, ac_cat):
    print(f"ac_cat is {ac_cat}")
    print(f"ac_cat.value is {ac_cat.value}")
    df_subset = df.loc[df.ActivityCategory==ac_cat.value]

    print(f"number of records in df_subset to scatter plot: {len(df_subset):,}")
    return df_subset.hvplot.scatter(x='ActivityCode', y='Duration')


freq2 = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name="Frequency", start=0, end=10, value=2)
phase2 = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name="Phase", start=0, end=np.pi)
@pn.depends(freq=freq2, phase=phase2)
def cosine(freq, phase):
    xs = np.linspace(0,np.pi)
    return hv.Curve((xs, np.cos(xs*freq+phase))).opts(
        responsive=True, min_height=400)

page = pn.Column(sizing_mode='stretch_width')

content1 = [
    pn.Row(ac_cat_radio_button), #grouping_vars_radio_button),
    scatter_detail_by_ac(df, ac_cat_radio_button),
]
content2 = [
    pn.Row(freq2, phase2),
    hv.DynamicMap(cosine),
]

link1 = pn.widgets.Button(name='Scatter')
link2 = pn.widgets.Button(name='Cosine')

template.sidebar.append(link1)
template.sidebar.append(link2)

template.main.append(page)

def load_content1(event):
    template.main[0].objects = content1


def load_content2(event):
    template.main[0].objects = content2

link1.on_click(load_content1)
link2.on_click(load_content2)

template.show()
```

I serve this Panel app locally by running (from shell):

```
panel serve app.py --autoreload
```

Also, here's the library versions I'm using, from my `requirements.in` (which I `pip-compile` into a requirements.txt/lockfile):

```
panel==v1.0.0rc6
pandas==1.5.3
holoviews==1.16.0a2
hvplot
pandas-gbq>=0.19.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue you encountered is that when you mark a function with `pn.depends` then you need to pass it as is to Panel, which will take care of re-executing it and re-rendering its output anytime one of the listed widgets in the `pn.depends` decorator is updated. Here's a simplified version of your code, fixing the issue you had:

```py
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import hvplot.pandas
import numpy as np

pn.extension()

# load detailed data
durations = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
activity_codes = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3']
activity_categories = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': durations,
                   'ActivityCode': activity_codes,
                   'ActivityCategory': activity_categories})


# Page 1 Widget Controls
ac_categories = ['A', 'B', 'C']
ac_cat_radio_button = pn.widgets.Select(name='Activity Category', options=ac_categories)

from functools import partial

# Page 1 Plotting Code
@pn.depends(ac_cat=ac_cat_radio_button)
def scatter_detail_by_ac(df=df, ac_cat=None):
    df_subset = df.loc[df.ActivityCategory==ac_cat]
    print(f"number of records in df_subset to scatter plot: {len(df_subset):,}")
    return df_subset.hvplot.scatter(x='ActivityCode', y='Duration')


pn.Column(ac_cat_radio_button, scatter_detail_by_ac)
```

Generally Panel users are now recommended to use `pn.bind` instead of `pn.depends` when they want to add interactivity in their apps. Its behavior is similar to `functools.partial` which makes it easier to approach, specially if you're already acquainted with `functools.partial`.

Now when it comes more specifically to data apps, such as yours, you can also leverage `hvplot.interactive` which is an API with which you can replace pipeline values by Panel widgets. I re-wrote your cool app using this API:

```py
import pandas as pd
import panel as pn
import hvplot.pandas
import numpy as np

pn.extension(sizing_mode='stretch_width')

# load detailed data
durations = np.random.randint(0, 10, size=10)
activity_codes = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'C3']
activity_categories = ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C', 'C']

df = pd.DataFrame({'Duration': durations,
                   'ActivityCode': activity_codes,
                   'ActivityCategory': activity_categories})


# App 1
w_ac_cat = pn.widgets.Select(name='Activity Category', options=['A', 'B', 'C'])
dfi = df.interactive()
dfi = dfi.loc[dfi.ActivityCategory == w_ac_cat]
app1 = dfi.hvplot.scatter(x='ActivityCode', y='Duration', responsive=True, min_height=400)

# App 2

def cosine(freq, phase):
    xs = np.linspace(0, np.pi)
    return pd.DataFrame(dict(y=np.cos(xs*freq+phase)), index=xs)

w_freq = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name="Frequency", start=0, end=10, value=2)
w_phase = pn.widgets.FloatSlider(name="Phase", start=0, end=np.pi)
dfi_cosine = hvplot.bind(cosine, w_freq, w_phase).interactive()
app2 = pn.Column(
    pn.Row(*dfi_cosine.widgets()),
    dfi_cosine.hvplot(responsive=True, min_height=400).output()
)

# Template

page = pn.Column(sizing_mode='stretch_width')
link1 = pn.widgets.Button(name='Scatter')
link2 = pn.widgets.Button(name='Cosine')
template = pn.template.FastListTemplate(
    title='My Dashboard', main=[page], sidebar=[link1, link2]
)

def load_content1(event):
    template.main[0][:] = [app1]

def load_content2(event):
    template.main[0][:] = [app2]

link1.on_click(load_content1)
link2.on_click(load_content2)

template.show()
```

[image]